# Why does CloudFormation require Quantity for certain List types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I noticed that `Quantity` is a required field on [`AWS::CloudFront::Distribution OriginGroups`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origingroups.html):

```json
{
  "Items" : [ OriginGroup, ... ],
  "Quantity" : Integer
}
```

> **Items**
>
> The items (origin groups) in a distribution.
>
> Required: No
>
> Type: List of OriginGroup

> **Quantity**
>
> The number of origin groups.
>
> Required: Yes
>
> Type: Integer

Why doesn't CloudFormation infer it from `items.count`?

Comment: thanks - that's a good question, will try to take it up with the dev team